# i m trying to install the npm packages and facing this error A complete log of this run can be found in:

Tags: node.js, npm

i m trying to install the npm packages and facing this error

```
code 127
npm ERR! path C:\Users\manis\OneDrive\Desktop\code\workspaceui\node_modules\node
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Program Files\git\bin\bash.exe -c node installArchSpecificPackage
npm ERR! /c/Users/manis/OneDrive/Desktop/code/workspaceui/node_modules/.bin/node: line 8: C:\Users\manis\OneDrive\Desktop\code\workspace-ui\node_modules\.bin/../node/bin/node: No such file or directory

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\manis\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-13T11_08_47_085Z-debug-0.log
```

i m trying to install the npm packages and facing this error

Comment: can you please share the command with us as well

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify that Node.js is installed on your system. You can do this by opening a terminal or command prompt and running the command node -v. If Node.js is not installed, you can download and install it from the official Node.js website (https://nodejs.org).
2. Check if the path to the node executable is correctly set. The error message indicates that it is looking for the node executable at C:\Users\manis\OneDrive\Desktop\code\workspace-ui\node_modules.bin/../node/bin/node. Ensure that the path is correct and that the node executable exists at that location.
3. If the path is incorrect or the node executable is missing, you may need to reinstall the dependencies for your project. In the project's root directory, delete the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json file. Then, open a terminal or command prompt in that directory and run npm install to reinstall the dependencies.
4. If you're using a specific version of Node.js, ensure that it is compatible with the project's dependencies. You can check the engines field in the package.json file of your project to see the required Node.js version. If the installed Node.js version is incompatible, you may need to update or switch to the correct version.
5. If the issue persists, try running the command with a different shell. Instead of using Git Bash, you can try using the default command prompt or another compatible shell.

**One of this may be the answer**